# Can I ask "self-learning" questions about handmade stuff?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Hi!

Can I ask (and maybe self-answer) questions about [computer modding](http://www.crazypc.com/articles/articles.htm) or [handmade stuff how-to](http://www.instructables.com/)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think they are too small to be in scope. The url is *diy*, but the name is *Home Improvement*, so we tend to discuss larger stuff.